# Daily Deviation Picture Frame on RPi

Tags: pi-3, pi-2, raspbian-stretch, linux, raspbian-wheezy

This guide, [Raspberry Pi - Daily Deviations Picture Frame](http://theswitchtolinux.blogspot.com/2012/12/raspberry-pi-daily-deviations-picture.html?m=1), seems to be not working anymore. I tried different methods and it seems that the code in getting images from Deviantart daily deviations seems to be the problem. Can someone help me on this one?

Comment: Hello, have you attempted any debugging yourself or can you add any error messages you are seeing to your question. A quick look at the original guide and the first problem I see is that the scraper script is looking for `http://...` in the RSS feed whereas the feed seems to be using is using secure URLs now.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) But most of us are not willing to follow complete linked tutorials to understand the question. It is really to much effort if you read some questions a day. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I'm new to this as well as to coding in Raspberry Pi. I'm sorry I can't show any problems but I think @RogerJones is correct about Devianart. When I run the code, no images is downloaded from the site. Aside from that, I think the code is a bit old. I've tried searching the codes function but it seems there is a different way to code that now. Any advise on what code should I use to download images (mainly jpg and png) from deviantart's daily deviation and slideshow it on a monitor? Thank you very much!